# Android Notification doesn't pop-up at given time

Tags: android

I just started working coverting my iOS app to Android.
But I'm having the following problem.

I created multiple classes so the alert pops-up.
But the problem is that the alert pop-ups every 5/10 seconds instead of the given time.
I know this has something to do with the following code:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000, 10000, pendingIntent);
```

But the strangest thing is that the given time above that code doesn't trigger any thing:
(Otherwise I could've just deleted the last line of code)

```
private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {
    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 18);

    Intent open = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    open.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, open, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(MyApp.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000, 10000, pendingIntent);
```

What's wrong with that code because the alarm doesn't pop-up at 17:18 but each time after 5 or 10 seconds.
The service that i've created to display the notification doesn't start at 17:18 to display the message.
Does this has something to do with my timezone (Amsterdam Time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're passing in the wrong values for .setRepeating. Have a look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

It looks to me like you're saying:
broadcast for the first time 5 seconds from now, then every 10 seconds after that repeat

Comment: Yes that's what it does now I just want it to go off at the specific time given above but it didn't work - I updated my first post to.

Comment: Because you're setting updateTime, but then not actually doing anything with it. The second parameter you pass into .setRepeating should be how long until the intent is broadcast for the first time. I think you want to use updateTime.getTimeInMillis() as the second parameter. What you're using now seems to be how long the device has been running (since last restart) + 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the following code worked for me! alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);